# Using @Html.Raw in for loop - ASP .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a model in my index.cshtml:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <p style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Translation)
  </p>
}
```

And I'm trying to use @Html.Raw to display the raw text inside of tags since I am using TinyMCE Rich Text Editor to edit "item.Translation". I want the raw text like this:

> " He said: "Come", so it came. Then He said: "Go", so it went "

but instead I am getting results like this:

```
> <p>He said: <em>"Come"<em>, so it came. Then He said: "Go", so it
> went<p>
```

I tried this:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <p style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
   @Html.Raw(modelItem => item.Translation)
  </p>
}
```

and:

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
  <p style="padding: 0; margin: 0">
   @Html.Raw(Model.Translation)
  </p>
}
```

but nothing worked.